# Restrict paste in contenteditable (HTML / JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I would like to prevent the user from pasting non allowed markup in a `contenteditable` div.

I would like to restrict paste to bold, italic, strike, underline and links.

What is the best way (I'm using `jQuery`) ?

**This is not a duplicate of [JQuery Text Editor Paste Without Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497333/jquery-text-editor-paste-without-formatting).** I don't want to paste without formatting. I want to select / restrict to some markups.

I already read the following questions, none provides a clear answer:

- [JQuery Text Editor Paste Without Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497333/jquery-text-editor-paste-without-formatting)
- [How to filter user pasted content in contenteditable div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822471/how-to-filter-user-pasted-content-in-contenteditable-div)
- [Javascript trick for 'paste as plain text` in execCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027137/javascript-trick-for-paste-as-plain-text-in-execcommand)
- [Contenteditable allowing only plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764304/contenteditable-allowing-only-plain-text?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Text Editor Paste Without Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497333/jquery-text-editor-paste-without-formatting)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822471/how-to-filter-user-pasted-content-in-contenteditable-div

Comment: This is not a duplicate of JQuery Text Editor Paste Without Formatting. Restrict paste is not the same as paste without formating

Answer (score 15):

Restrict pasted content by listening to the editable element's `paste` event. Inside this event, you can filter the data the user is attempting to paste by using a regular expression.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('p');

el.addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
  // Get user's pasted data
  let data = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html') ||
      e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  
  // Filter out everything except simple text and allowable HTML elements
  let regex = /<(?!(\/\s*)?(a|b|i|em|s|strong|u)[>,\s])([^>])*>/g;
  data = data.replace(regex, '');
  
  // Insert the filtered content
  document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, data);

  // Prevent the standard paste behavior
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<p contenteditable>Try pasting content into this paragraph. The pasted content can include a <b>BOLD</b>, <i>ITALIC</i>, <s>STRIKE</s>, or <u>UNDERLINE</u>. It can also include a <a href='#'>LINK</a>.</p>
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this work with both pasted text and text that was dragged and dropped into the contenteditable?

Comment: @MikeMichaels You could try listening to `input` events, when the `inputType` value is `'insertFromDrop'`. A full answer would merit its own SO question.